# choosing autoconf and automake versions

Tags: c, linux, compilation, autoconf, automake

I see there are many version of autoconf and automake available in my ubuntu linux.
If I want create a new project from scratch, what's best choice, latest versions or older versions?

Comment: The best choice in my humble opinion is to use a different build system altogether, if you can. CMake, for example, is much less horrible than autotools and works pretty well. SCons is also quite nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go with the latest version.  It's only developers who are rebuilding the configure system that need to use `autoconf` and `automake` (and thus need to have the newer version installed), which likely just means "you"; it won't affect users who are just building your project using your distributed configure files.

Comment: +1, Additionally, I usually make nighly snapshots of repositories and include the generated configure script in them. This lets people send patches without much difficulty. Those who have commit access will also (typically) have the appropriate version of autotools installed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I asked such question because I'm writing something like an apache httpd module. Probably (I bet) no one will ever help me.

Comment: @freedev: Sure.  And the newer versions of autoconf at least give you access to more pre-built tests and things, so it's definitely a win.

Comment: Although I normally agree whole-heartedly to go with the latest release, there are some fairly large regressions in autoconf 2.66, and you might want to stick with 2.65 until 2.67 is released.